# Will Skyrim work properly if mods and main files are split over two HDDs?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods, hardware, hard-drive

I would like to know if anyone has experience running skyrim and it's mods across two separate data drives. I am upgrading my rig to a solid state, but it is only 500GB. If I want to play a game like Skyrim, with main game files installed on the SSD, and the mods on an HDD, will this work?

Will the game only load as fast as the slowest assets involved? For instance, will Skyrim only load as fast as the modded assets on an HDD will allow?

Comment: This would depend greatly on which game, and how it's been architected to handle multiple drives.  We could probably tell you if a specific game would handle it, but this is too general to be answerable right now.

Comment: I've used skyrim as an example, so u suppose that should be the game in question

Comment: I'd recommend editing the question to just focus on Skyrim, then.

Comment: Done and done. The question is now tailored to skyrim itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, but it could have serious impacts on performance - script lag, which is determined by many factors such as your PC specs, etc. However, it could work without problems at all, it just depends on the PC.

I recommend using 'Mod Organizer' (for Skyrim) to do this seamlessly. Just remember, it *can* have script lag, but it may also not have any at all. Good luck if you do try!

EDIT: This is just regarding your mention of Skyrim. Extrapolating from that, I assume all Bethesda games would work as such, but those are optimized for modding. Other games which are not so keen on optimal modding experiences will suffer script lag, or may not work at all.

Source: Personal experience on several PCs